# Массовое обновление товаров на других языках

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpml

Есть первый сайт на одном языке (например русском) и есть второй сайт на нескольких языках. Мультиязычность сделана на WPML.

С помощью WPALL export-import периодически происходит синхронизация товаров с первого сайта на второй - обновление цен, остатков, атрибутов, сопутствующих и других данных.

После этого WPML требует обновить переводы.
Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно это делать массово, чтобы не заходить в каждый и тупо тыкать кнопки?